# Getting error when running my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error now that I changed the bundleID and name of my flutter app. I had errors in the build.gradle but I upgraded my JDK to 17 and they went away. Now, I am getting this error when I try to run the app:

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: 
Exception occurred while executing 'install':
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.pm.PackageManagerInternal.freeStorage(java.lang.String, long, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.allocateBytes(StorageManagerService.java:4047)
    at android.os.storage.StorageManager.allocateBytes(StorageManager.java:2286)
    at android.os.storage.StorageManager.allocateBytes(StorageManager.java:2365)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageI
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

I am using vscode.

How do I fix this error?
Thanks

UPDATE:
I just ran flutter run in the terminal and this is what I got:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25479): Process: com.kane.dealdiligence, PID: 25479
E/AndroidRuntime(25479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kane.dealdiligence/com.kane.dealdiligence.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kane.dealdiligence.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4047)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)      
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kane.dealdiligence.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~zBlGcSPj5Xqhv_hUY5rvmw==/com.kane.dealdiligence-N4SnEQbRRHUmrtqSr9f4Hw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4034)
E/AndroidRuntime(25479):        ... 12 more
```